# Разве такое может быть, что нет таблицы разделов в первом секторе жесткого диска? И с него нормально грузится Windows?

Tags: файловая-система, hex

Разве такое может быть, что нет таблицы разделов в первом секторе жесткого диска? И с него нормально грузится Windows?

Windows 7
NTFS
жесткий диск не разбит
[image: первый сектор диска, открытый в WinHex]

Comment: Если у вас вопрос к тому, что у вас выделено на скриншоте - это текст сообщений, которые выведутся когда соответственно отсутствует BOOTMGR или BOOTMGR сжат. Само наличие этого текста в файловой системе не говорит о том, что с BOOTMGR что-то не так.

Comment: Вот вам аналогия: есть программа, которая работает с базой данных. При определенных условиях программа может вывести сообщение "база данных повреждена". Если вы откроете exe файл программы hex редактором, то возможно вы найдете текст этого сообщения, но само наличие этого текста в exe файле не говорит о том, что прямо сейчас файл базы данных поврежден, а только о том, что при определенных условиях это сообщение может быть выведено программой.

Comment: Понял, что диск с VBR, но без MBR.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался! Это код загрузочной записи раздела (VBR), код главной загрузочной записи (MBR) надо было открыть в другой программе. Т.е. открыл жесткий диск в WinHex, подумал, что начинаться будет там с MBR, но он не соответствовал формату - отсюда и вопрос. Потом открыл диск в Виктории  - увидел правильный код MBR. Всё стало ясно.